# Component "CompnentName" has no route config

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I got some problem on routing in angular2
I want to make nested route in my service, but I'm stuck.

```html
@Component({
  selector : "app",
  directives : [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  template : `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})

@RouteConfig([
  {path: "/**", redirectTo: ['/User', {userId:0}, 'Main']},
  {path: "/users/:userId/...", component: User, name: "User", useAsDefault:true},
  {path: "/main", component: Main, name: "Main"}
])
```

this is my code in app.ts which is bootstrapping the app.

and below is the user.ts contains user component.

```html
@Component({
  selector : "user",
  directives : [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavBar, UserInfo, Main, Feeds, Notebook],
  template : `
  <div class="dotebook-main">
      <nav-bar></nav-bar>
      <div class="dotebook-view">
        <div class="dotebook-body">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
        <div class="dotebook-user">
          <user-info [user]="user"></user-info>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})

export class User{
  constructor(){
  }
}

@RouteConfig([
  {path: "/", redirectTo : ['Main']},
  {path: "/main", component: Main, name: 'Main', useAsDefault: true},
  {path: "/feeds", component: Feeds, name: "Feeds"},
  {path: "/notebook/:notebookId", component: Notebook, name: "Notebook"}
])
```

I want to make '/user/:userId' to be the root all the time,
and I want '/user/:userId/main' to be default page.

user component should have children routes like 
'/user/:userId/main' or '/user/:userId/feeds' and so on.
so I added '/...' at the end of the User component url in app.ts.

but I got problem at this point.

I think routing "Main" should be done in User Component but,
to make users to go "users/:userId/main" at the first time, 
I need to use "redirectTo" in the app.ts routeConfig.

and I got Component "User" has no route config error on this.

I think it's violation of the url hierarchy I made.
but I can't event guess what's the solution.

does anyone had the similar problem with this?
help!
thanks in advance!

Comment: "I want to make nested route in my service" sounds weird. Services don't have routes, only components. It's not obvious to what components the routes in your first code block are applied and not how the component looks like (or what component it is at all) where the routes in the 2nd code block are applied to.

Comment: oh I mean, I want User component to be shown always. the User Component has nav-bar component and another router-outlet in it, and when clicking 'a' tags for moving, then I want to make only the router-outlet in the User Component change

Answer (score 2):

The `@RouteConfig(..)` annotation has to be above the class declaration. Like this:

```
@Component({
  selector : "user",
  ...
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path: "/", redirectTo : ['Main']},
  {path: "/main", component: Main, name: 'Main', useAsDefault: true},
  {path: "/feeds", component: Feeds, name: "Feeds"},
  {path: "/notebook/:notebookId", component: Notebook, name: "Notebook"}
])
export class User{
  constructor(){
  }
}
```